# The general term of $\frac{2^2}{5!}-\frac{5^7}{6!}+\frac{8^{12}}{7!}-\frac{11^{17}}{8!}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can someone help me into finding the general term of this sequence? I have already tried at the denominator and according to my calculations I think it should be $(n+4)!$.
$$\frac{2^2}{5!} - \frac{5^7}{6!} + \frac{8^{12}}{7!} - \frac{11^{17}}{8!} + \cdots$$

Comment: What is $n$ in the sequence?

Comment: $(-1)^{n-1}\frac{(3n-1)^{5n-3}}{(n+4)!}$  ($n$ starts at $1$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break it down,

The numerator (minus the exponent)
$$2,5,8,11$$
This is basically an AP, $2+3(n-1)=3n-1$.

The exponent
$$2,7,12,17$$
This is basically another AP, $2+5(n-1)=5n-3$.

The denominator, yes you are right it's $(n+4)!$

The sign, it's $(+1)$ for even terms and $(-1)$ for odd terms, so it's $(-1)^{n+1}$

Altogether,
$$\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(3n-1)^{5n-3}}{(n+4)!}$$
for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$